# How to write $4.13\bar{9}$ in explicit form

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to write $4.13\bar{9}$ in an explicit form.

I know how to solve a problem similar to this, for a number like $2.\overline{17}$, where the bar starts at the first number after the comma:

I know that

$$2.\overline{17}=$$
$$2+\frac{17}{100}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{1}{100})^{n-1}=$$

$$2+\frac{17}{100}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{100}=}$$
$$2+\frac{17}{99}=\frac{215}{99}.$$

But I'm not 100% sure how to solve a problem where the bar starts at the third number after the comma.

Do I start the sum from $n=1$, like I did above? Do I start it for $n=3$ ?

I mean, would I write

$$4+\frac{13}{100}+\sum_{n=3}^\infty{\frac{9}{10^n}}$$or
$$4+\frac{13}{100}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{9}{10^n}}$$

?

I can't seem to understand which one to use.

Comment: It's the first alternative, the first term of the infinite series should be $\frac{9}{1000}$, so $n=3$ as the first. Then use that the sum of a geometric series with rate $r$ is the first term divided by $1-r$.

Comment: I start the sum for $n=1$ then ?

Comment: No $n=3$, so $10^3 = 1000$.

Comment: So if the bar started at the 5th number after the comma, would I start the sum from $n=5$ ?

Comment: Yes, if it were a single number that had a bar. Otherwise you have to do some grouping like in your first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4.13\bar{9} = 4  + \frac{13}{100} + \frac{9}{1000} + \frac{9}{10000} + \frac{9}{100000} + \ldots = 4 + \frac{13}{100} + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^n} = 4 + \frac{13}{100} + \frac{\frac{9}{1000}}{(1 - \frac{1}{10})}$.

Answer (score 3):

Mind that
$$
4.13\overline{9}=4.14=\frac{207}{50}.
$$

Comment: I know this, but would my professor accept this? He has given us 3 similar examples and didn't use this in any of them

Comment: I don't know if your prof would accept this answer, but as you know it is correct you can use it to check which one of your expressions is right.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do cases where the repeating block starts at the decimal point:
$$
x = 4.13\overline{9}
\\
100 x = 413.\overline{9} = 413 + 0.\overline{9} = 413 + 1 = 414
\\
x = \frac{414}{100} = \frac{207}{50}
$$